# Order results fulltext

Tags: mysql, sql

Following my query:

```
SELECT data1
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT id,
MATCH (
...
)
AGAINST (
...
) AS rank
FROM table2 t2
WHERE MATCH (
...
)
AGAINST (
....
)
) ORDER BY rank DESC
```

The problem is that I do not recognize rank outside where, in fact I see the following message:

> #1054 -  Unknown column 'rank' in 'order clause'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a SQL statement, you can only reference columns from tables/subqueries in the main `from` clause.  Your subquery is in the `where` clause.

You need to rewrite this as a `join`.  If `id` is unique in table2, this this will work:

```
select data1
from table1 t1 join
     (SELECT id, MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) AS rank
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE MATCH (...) AGAINST (....)
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
order by t2.rank
```

Otherwise, you need to take duplicates into account:

```
select distinct data1, rank
from table1 t1 join
     (SELECT id, MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) AS rank
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE MATCH (...) AGAINST (....)
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
order by t2.rank
```

Comment: The examples are really well done, you deserve the best answer! So thanks you!

Comment: tbh, I don't see the requirement for a subquery here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `WHERE EXISTS` and a subquery.

```
SELECT data1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT id,
    MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) AS rank
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) 
) ORDER BY rank DESC
```

In this context, MySQL [ignores](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) the selected fields. It could as well read:

```
SELECT data1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 42
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) 
) ORDER BY rank DESC
```

And it would work just the same.

Think of a `WHERE EXISTS`-subquery as returning a boolean and nothing but that boolean.

If you want the rank to be calculated from table2, you will have to add a `JOIN` to your main query (and possibly a `GROUP BY` clause).

**Edit: Example**

Most probably you don't need the `WHERE EXISTS` clause. (Your question is too unspecific to determine, so here's the standard case)

```
SELECT t1.data1, MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) AS rank
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON (MATCH (...) AGAINST (...))
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.data, rank
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

If there is only a *maximum of one* matching row in table2, you can get away without the `GROUP BY` clause, and just do a straight join

```
SELECT t1.data1, MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) AS rank
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON (MATCH (...) AGAINST (...))
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Comment: Could you give me an example please?